# Debug Q With GDB Debugger

Tags: c++, gdb

This is really a general question.
And I've tried looking around for help but it's about the gdp debugger.
I compile a program, it takes two strings as arguments.

I run it with r and the two parameters following it, but when I insert a break like ' break 33 ' and break at line 33 and then run it again, I cannot step into it and it doesn't stop at my break.
I can't step break continue etc.

```
gcc -g -o debugme debugme.c
Directory: /home/
Tue Oct  6 20:03:14 EDT 2015
[]$ debugme "hi there" "bye bye"
String '0' - 'debugme'
String '1' - 'hi there'
String '2' - 'bye bye'
Total number of command-line arguments: 2
(gdb)
Tue Oct  6 20:06:56 EDT 2015
[]$ cd cosc220
[]$ gdb debugme
GNU gdb (GDB; openSUSE 13.1) 7.6.50.20130731-cvs
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-suse-linux".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.opensuse.org/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
..                                                                                                            
Reading symbols from /home/...done.                                                
(gdb) break 33                                                                                                
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005c7: file debugme.c, line 33.                                                            
(gdb) delete 1
(gdb)
(gdb) break 33
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4005c7: file debugme.c, line 33.
(gdb)
```

What do I need to type for this to work?
It tells me my program isn't running, I try viewing my call stack and it's empty
I type r for run later (I just didn't include it here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we didn't have it installed on the server at my school...
Face-palm, it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hit  r at the gdb so that your program again start running.

Comment: I am able to get it to run but I can't get it to break and it doesn't step or anything

Comment: @aaabbbaaa You start gdb session, then you set break points, then you hit r , program runs and stops at the breakpoint, then you hit c, and program reaches its end, Then again to restart the whole session, you need to hit r again. and all the break point remain valid. But if you somehow exit the gdb session, then all your break point are lost and you need to set all break points again.

Comment: hmm. il try this tomorrow. i dont have linux on my system. hopefully it works. thanks @Ritesh

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need to type for this to work?

You should probably read an introduction, such as [this one](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/).

The command you are looking for is `run`, but once you run your program to the breakpoint, it's likely that you'll have more questions, so starting at introduction may still be a good idea.

Comment: I'm able to get it to run but I can't get it to break.